# Disable href in lignting component controller OR helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an anchor tag inside the lightning component as follows

```
<aura:attribute name="displayAdvancedSearch" type="Boolean"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.displayAdvancedSearch}"
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabIndex="-1" class='slds-float_right font" onclick="{!c.showBasicSearch}"> Basic Search </a>
<aura:set attribute="else">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabIndex="-1" class='slds-float_right font" onclick="{!c.showAdvancedSearch}"> Advanced Search </a>
<aura:set>
<aura:if>
```

When I click Basic search I will show some fields in UI and when I click Advanced Search I will show some fields in the UI
when I am in Advanced Search, I want to prevent the user from clicking "Basic Search" and vice versa.
Is there a way to disable the anchor tag like in the controller or helper of the lightning component?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your click handlers showBasicSearch and showAdvancedSearch you should be getting the event as a parameter. You can suppress the event that way.

```
showBasicSearch : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
},
```

Comment: I saw your message, its not working as expected, when I am in Advanced search link then Basic Search link should be disabled and vice versa

Comment: You are already checking a variable for v.displayAdvancedSearch, are you setting that in your controller? It looks like you are trying to not render the link entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my query by adding 2 lightning buttons instead of using anchor tag.